# how can I make a right click context menu in React (without 3rd part libraries)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contextmenu

I want when I right-click in the hierarchy list of files a context menu appears with options like Rename, Delete, and new Files.

I have a div that contains all of these items (Rename, Delete, etc) so I want when I click on the right click the div appears in the same behavior of of this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-contextmenu).

Answer (score 0):

like this ?

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  const contextMenu = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
    return;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p onContextMenu={contextMenu}>
          Edit <code>App.tsx</code> and save to test HMR updates.
        </p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: yeah, thanks. how to add a right-click menu?

Comment: when the onContextMenu event is triggered, you can add your own custom menu list